# how can i add extra spaces before any special character

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, swift-string

how to add extra spaces before any Special character in string ,in Swift, for example if i have string

```
var str = "#StackOverFlow@is$awesome"

 " #StackOverFlow  @is  $awesome"   // i have to achieve this...add empty spaces before every #
```

how can we solve and achieve this in Swift

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: The question is totally different from the duplicated one. OP is asking "before any Special character" not before a specific character

Comment: @KEERTHIj What has that question got to do with anything?

Comment: Leo is right ....I want spaces before any special character.....my title was very clear ...maybe example get some people confused I guess

Comment: You can make your question clearer by posting your own attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match any special character `"[^\\w]"` which means any non word character and replace by the same match `"$0"`preceded by white spaces. If you would like to exclude whitespaces from being replaced you can use `"[^\\w|\\s]"`:

```
let str =  "#StackOverFlow#is#awesome"
let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\w]",
                          with: "   $0",
                          options: .regularExpression)


print(result)  // "   #StackOverFlow   #is   #awesome\n"
```

---

```
let str2 =  "•StackOverFlow•is•awesome"
let result2 = str2.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\w]",
                          with: "   $0",
                          options: .regularExpression)


print(result2)  // "   •StackOverFlow   •is   •awesome\n"
```